# Keynote default style for graphic elements

Tags: graphics, keynote, iwork

Every time I make a new line in Keynote, it is white and 1-point, so it can hard to find and reposition. I have tried looking for a contextual menu that says "Assign current style as default" but am not finding anything. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can get the default behavior :

Open the inspector > Text tab > Bullets > Select **No Bullets**

Comment: Thanks but I was talking about a line shape, not a line of text.